# host-context not working in Angular

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular2-template

**The button background is red, when it should be green**

*i.e. the conditional styling controlled by :host-context is not activated?*

#### Child component styles commander.scss

```
commander {
  button {
    background-color: red;
  }
  :host-context(.enough-space) .btn-theme {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

#### Child component template commander.html

```
<button class="btn-theme" (click)="demand()">{{requestText}}</button>
```

#### Host component template front.html

```
...
<commander (command)="requestPage()" [requestText]="requestText"></commander>
```

#### Host component code front.ts

```
@Component({
             selector: "page-front",
             templateUrl: "front.html",
             host: {'class': 'enough-space'}
           })
export class FrontPage {
...
}
```

Much of this is based on https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngclass-ngstyle/ so it should work - the only real differences I can see is that I have separate files for the templates and styles and I am using Angular within Ionic.

#### Packages used

```
"@angular/common": "5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.0",
```

#### Works in different environment

Here is the same code in stackblitz, and it is working fine, the button is green as it should be: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-host-context

The only differences I can see is that stackblitz uses Angular 4.1.3 and Ionic 3.5.2? Although I am not sure how exactly they have set up the rest of their environment.

Comment: Is the class `enough-space` added to the DOM as expected? Can you reproduce in http://stackblitz.com

Comment: Are you adding other classes to `<page-front>`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer When inspecting page-front I can confirm that it has the following classes `class="enough-space ion-page show-page"` - and I am talking about confirming this in my environment not stackblitz

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer see edited question with stackblitz

Comment: Ok, so in StackBlitz you get the expected behavior. Sorry I don't know about Ionic.